# No such table issue

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse

Another Java question involving the SQLite side of things.

I've run my app and all is fine until i come to add the inserted data. Im getting an error in the Log cat of '12-31 22:54:51.133: I/Database(273): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: peopleTable'. This obviously the leads to the fact I cant use my insert method to add to the DB.

I've tried renaming the DB, I cant see anything wrong with my table create statement, or my onCreate/Upgrade methods.

Heres the code:

Code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + "TEXT NOT NULL);");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXCISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

And the logcat:

```
12-31 22:54:51.133: I/Database(273): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such    table: peopleTable
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273): Error inserting persons_hotness=5 persons_name=F
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: peopleTable: , while compiling: INSERT INTO peopleTable(persons_hotness,  persons_name) VALUES(?, ?);
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at com.example.sqliteexample.HotOrNot.createEntry(HotOrNot.java:174)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at com.example.sqliteexample.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:57)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-31 22:54:51.158: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 23:17:38.508: W/KeyCharacterMap(273): No keyboard for id 0
12-31 23:17:38.508: W/KeyCharacterMap(273): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-31 23:17:40.238: D/AndroidRuntime(273): Shutting down VM
12-31 23:17:40.238: W/dalvikvm(273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.sqliteexample.SQLView }
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.example.sqliteexample.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:94)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-31 23:17:40.259: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you verified the table is being created in the db? What value is in DATABASE_TABLE?

Comment: Have you verified that `onCreate()` is actually called? Add a `Log.d()` call to output something in your logcat. Also, it is probably not a good idea to drop your table in `onUpgrade()`. For now, you should simply leave this method blank.

Comment: Your `Java code` and your `logcat` seems in no relation at all. Like you are `creating and dropping table in java code` while `logcat says inserting data into DB`.

Comment: Mike, would I need to verify this through the Log.d method? The DATABASE_TABLE is a variable which holds the value 'peopleTable' for the table name for the table creation.

Comment: smit. I have other methods in my code that will insert the data from two 'editTexts' of my xml. I get this error when I press the button and it trys to insert the data. I didnt include the other code as I just thought i'd see if anyone could find any issues with my create and upgrade methods.

Comment: @user1352057 Did you confirmed that your table has been created after your event?.

Comment: what is in '(HotOrNot.java:174)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
KEY_HOTNESS + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

that looks like it could cause issue. is there a space (`" "`) between the 2 string values, like the other columns in the table declaration?

Answer (score 4):

Change `EXCISTS` to `EXISTS` and it'll work (or at least will solve one of your problems) 
 ;)

Comment: Ty alfasin. I've edited it to the correct spelling. But sadly still have the exact same number of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ty for your help guys. Tuned out to be a combination of the errors you guys saw, plus the fact i was using the same DB version on the upGrade.